# Login customizado no Django, qual a melhor forma de aperfeiçoar?

Tags: python, django, webforms, login

No momento preciso logar no `django.admin` e no login que eu mesmo tenho criado em um `models.py | Class Pessoa`. Desta forma não é funcional, pois o `admin` precisa estar logado para que um usuário normal logue na tela principal(dashboard).

No momento meu Login é feito desta forma:

```
    def login(request):
        form = PessoaForm(request.POST, None)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('dashboard')
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Ainda não descobri uma forma de fazer logout.
Estou tentando desenvolver um login bruto, por exemplo:

```
def login(request):
    i = 0
    counter = 10
    exitloop = False
    form = PessoaForm(request.POST, None)
    user = Pessoa.cnpj
    pwd = Pessoa.senha
    while i < counter or exitloop == 1:
        if user == Pessoa.cnpj and pwd == Pessoa.senha:
            exitloop = 1
            return redirect('dashboard')
    i = i+1
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Mas ainda acredito não ser a melhor forma. Observação: Preciso que tenha um filtro de `@login_required` porem com esse login customizado e uma forma de fazer logout.

**Agradeço qualquer direcionamento ou ajuda, tanto para a codificação quanto para a sintaxe.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer fazer um Login Personalizado, sendo assim você terá que estudar "AbstractBaseUser".

E para LOGOUT é Simples:

1.Use estes comandos no views.py

2.Existe bibliotecas para Logout e redirecionar URLS; (Vai estar no código abaixo)

3.Seja feliz.

```
#bibliotecas
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse


#Exija que o usuário esteja logado para executar o comando, isso evitará futuros problemas.
@login_required
#coloque o nome diferente que logout para não gerar conflito com o comando importado logout
def logout_view(request):
    #executarará logout
    logout(request)
    # Realizará o logout e irá para pagina desejada,neste caso INDEX.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/